# Find the generating function of a sequence

Tags: code-golf

Given a set of space-delimited integers, you've gotta either return a function that can generate that sequence, or return "There isn't any such function".

Sample input:

```
"1 11 41 79"
 - x^3+x^2-1

"12 38 78"
 - 7x^2 + 5x
```

The operations that the functions can contain are: +-/* and exponentiation.

If anyone has any other ideas LMK. As this is a code-golf, the shortest code will win.

Comment: This is a generalized form of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/polynomial-interpolation, but I don't blame you for missing that (who knows what polynomial interpolation even is?)

Comment: Also, why is this a popularity contest?

Comment: In fact there are at least three other questions asking for polynomial interpolation in addition to the one @beary605 mentions.

Comment: The answer to the first sequence should read `-2x^3+22x^2-42x+23`. The generator function you have will produce `1 11 35 79`.

Comment: Also, the title is somewhat misleading. [Generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) generate sequences in the _coefficients_.

Comment: I've changed the criteria to code-golf. As all of the solutions will do exactly the same thing, I don't see a need for subjective evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python 256 bytes

```
a=raw_input().split();r=range(len(a));m=[[(i+1.)**p for p in r]+[int(a[i])]for i in r]
for j in r:s=m[j];m=[map(lambda a,b:a-b*(i[j]-(i==s))/s[j],i,s)for i in m]
while~j:
 c=m[j][-1]
 if c:print('%+.15g'%c)[s>c>0:j>=c*c==1or 18]+('x^%d'%j)[:j*j],;s=0
 j-=1
```

Sets up a system of linear equations, matrix style, and then uses Gaussian elimination to solve. Quite a few bytes are spent pretty-printing the output. Non-integer solutions are displayed to 15 digits of accuracy.

As every sequence of *n* real numbers can be generated by a polynomial of order no more than *n-1*, the "function does not exist" case is not handled.

Sample usage:

```
$ echo 1 11 41 79 | python find-poly.py
-2x^3 +22x^2 -42x +23

$ echo 1 11 35 79 | python find-poly.py
x^3 +x^2 -1

$ echo 12 38 78 | python find-poly.py
7x^2 +5x

$ echo 43 12 -5 19 57 | python find-poly.py
-2.25x^4 +27x^3 -98.75x^2 +110x +7
```

Answer (score 2):

There was no restriction in using any specific library, so here is a solution in Python using Sympy

**Python 2.x: 71 Characters**

```
from sympy import*
print interpolate(map(int,raw_input().split()),abc.x)
```

Comment: That is quite nice, althought I did need to explicitly import sympy.abc to get it to work.