# Rational Polynomial Interpolation

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

### Explanation

In this task you'll be given a set of *N* points *(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>),…,(x<sub>N</sub>,y<sub>N</sub>)* with distinct *x<sub>i</sub>* values and your task is to interpolate a polynomial through these points. If you know what Lagrange interpolation is you can skip this section.

The goal of a [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) is to construct the (unique) polynomial *p(x)* with degree *N-1* (for higher degrees there are infinite solutions) for which *p(x<sub>i</sub>) = y<sub>i</sub>* for all *i = 1…N*. One way to do so is to construct *N* Lagrange basis polynomials and form a linear combination. Such a basis polynomial is defined as follows:

[image: l_i(x) := \cfrac{x-x_1}{x_i-x_1}\cdots\cfrac{x-x_{i-1}}{x_i-x_{i-1}}\cdot\cfrac{x-x_{i+1}}{x_i-x_{i+1}}\cdots\cfrac{x-x_N}{x_i-x_N}]

As you can see if you evaluate *l<sub>i</sub>* at the points x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>i-1</sub>
,x<sub>i+1</sub>,…
,x<sub>N</sub> it is 0 by construction and 1 for x<sub>i</sub>, multiplying by y<sub>i</sub> will only change the value at x<sub>i</sub> and set it to y<sub>i</sub>. Now having N such polynomials that are 0 in every point except one we can simply add them up and get the desired result. So the final solution would be:

[image: p(x) = \overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}} y_i \cdot l_i(x)]

### Challenge

- the input will consist of *N* data points in any reasonable format (list of tuples, Points, a set etc.)
- the coordinates will all be of integer value
- the output will be a polynomial in any reasonable format: list of coefficients, Polynomial object etc.
- the output has to be exact - meaning that some solutions will have rational coefficients
- formatting doesn't matter (`2/2` instead of `1` or `1 % 2` for `1/2` etc.) as long as it's reasonable
- you won't have to handle invalid inputs (for example empty inputs or input where *x* coordinates are repeated)

### Testcases

These examples list the coefficients in decreasing order (for example `[1,0,0]` corresponds to the polynomial *x<sup>2</sup>*):

```
[(0,42)] -> [42]
[(0,3),(-18,9),(0,17)] -> undefined (you don't have to handle such cases)
[(-1,1),(0,0),(1,1)] -> [1,0,0]
[(101,-42),(0,12),(-84,3),(1,12)] -> [-4911/222351500, -10116/3269875, 692799/222351500, 12]
```

Comment: [Relevant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/polynomial-interpolation), [relevant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84779/shamirs-secret-sharing) and [relevant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80030/discrete-convolution-or-polynomial-multiplication/150681)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 14 bytes

```
polinterpolate
```

Takes two lists `[x1, ..., xn]` and `[y1, ..., yn]` as input. Outputs a polynomial.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8L8gPyczryS1CEgnlqT@LygC8jTSNKINDQx1DHR0LUx0DGN1onVNjHQMjXSMgUSspuZ/AA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 35 bytes, without built-in

```
f(x,y)=y/matrix(#x,,i,j,x[j]^(i-1))
```

Takes two lists `[x1, ..., xn]` and `[y1, ..., yn]` as input. Outputs a list of coefficients.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgFAXQj2l5wpV85tDSl4iBi/GEQsRBv95cznRKrKKfMmeijqGusb@xVem0dUCQ0X0ON4lmpWap8jVK5NkwDPTpwAFeOwu2OBZhrR8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Enlist](https://github.com/alexander-liao/enlist), 25 bytes

```
Ḣ‡ḟ¹‡,€-÷_Ḣ¥€§æc/§₱W€$↙·Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83LySwu@f8/OtrQwFDHQEfXwkTHMFYnWtfESMfQSMcYSMTGPmpY8HDHokcNCx/umH9oJ5DWedS0Rvfw9nig6KGlQPah5YeXJesfWv6oaWM4kKvyqG3moe0Pd646tPz/fwA)

---

Monadic link takes an array of length 2 (e.g., `[[101,0,-84,1],[-42,12,3,12]]`) as input. The first element of the array is list of x value, the second is list of y value. Output as list of coefficient in increasing degree.

Because @HyperNeutrino forgot to wrap numbers in rational wrapper if it is evaluated in list, ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83LySwu@f//4c4F////jzaMBQA)) the argument must be hardcoded in the code.

The `↙` is necessary because HyperNeutrino make some mistake in implementing `·` I don't know (or is this a feature? Not sure)

Equivalent Mathematica code:

```
Expand[ Table[
 Times @@ ((z - #)/(xi - #) & /@ DeleteCases[x, xi])
 , {xi, x}] . y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xCsIwGIT3PMWBIC0kttUOXYSA@gbdSoeoP/hDW4rJkBry7DE6HPd9y91s3Itm4/hhUgpeYos4I4SmbiRqCdW1Ek2UCKo9Zso5/SpGIW5@NctzQG/uEw0CPc9koTWK4gOFXVkVnv@APSqNK03k6GIs2SE/eR5LgbzsOUscccA2ppTU@ubFfQE)

where `x` and `y` are list of coordinates. This prints the polynomial.

---

What Enlist have for this challenge:

- Built in rational number support
- Convolution `æc` (my feature request)

Comment: If you need a rational number version of Jelly, [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m) might be worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/), with [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/), 301 bytes

See [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/suhailsh7/polynomial-interpolation-hermite-method) for how it works.

---

Golfed version. 301 bytes, it can be golfed much more. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZIxTsMwGIXFmlNYZbFTp8RphypSpl6gu_EQqANWEttyHCkW4iQsXeAynABOgx23oIou1tPT-z-9_5ffPrSzz0oej--jbbLt900meq2MBXLstQP1AKROGqN6ICw3VqluAKfEo-ofhKytUHIIwV3MzYMrrTonVS_q7hzf_zk-vE8OvAEdbPGESsPtaCTYQzqMPaRSr7RRBzgh0CgDJiAk2EHvHnjHLYcTbhEWiKEUZgSlKRRLgu7OU5e5bKItixwROKaWTxx2XHo6YrQsM8LQ3KXxeffbJRSJ7VLnCTOgvQQ4hFC82tfnVFGSE5zjbLvBhCWuotmmwKTAa_-w5FYbIS1sFi8dzD20er2XC3Rhk-t2cd1e_7MXjuYsjfiloyRoEnURdBH1Ouh5ugoro9ITTtz5AKeVzh_iBw)

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations as C
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
def l(k,x):return P([sum([np.prod(x) for x in C(np.delete(x,k),i)])*(-1)**(i+1)/np.prod(np.delete(x,k)-x[k]) for i in range(len(x))][::-1])
def f(x,y):return sum(l(k,x)*y[k] for k in range(len(y)))
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJBbpwwFJW69Cm-phubwHTMZBGNwg266J6iigz2xAJsyzYVVtWTdJNNe6ieoMeobcgMisICfT_e-7z35F9_tHfPSr68_J4cLx7-fvgnRq2MAzmN2kNrQWrEjRpBOGacUoOFlXFW45OQrRNKWlg4SbTXavBSjaIdXqlfrghCH-HCHLhnBp_bi2nlhcFTa4UFPslzXIY6xmHAfQ4zOSEIj4QKBibxTNKxtTZYAdzD4woveHrN3_rAnuu-WY9nFXJUIca-YwNzDM859BtBx6KzkEOZhaaN6vCqK-K-DfmsGOeBVjc3jAehACEhhcFyNX2l71utmeywnUZcX_eTpJujblvk-uMcBGkIZIALSrIMiztK4NPW61tTe8O-M2MZ3nwwzE1GbtrHiUoQSh3zUIUnp5UV7cXWZ5L50F6y199ixaI9IVE7VzU90PyQFw_3OW2Qr-rivsxpmR_Dq0HaCOkw3_0Y8CGsq35-lTuyRem7aPkuenyL7nx9aLJl9Z2vaZzpMpdxLpf5GOckrmJQcrqtTbHJcuHXe_96__8D)

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations 
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

# get the Lagrange basis function
def l(k, x):
    n = len(x)
    assert (k < len(x))
    
    x_k = x[k]
    x_copy = np.delete(x, k)
    
    denominator = np.prod(x_copy - x_k)
    
    coeff = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        coeff.append(sum([np.prod(x) for x in combinations(x_copy, i)]) * (-1)**(i+1) / denominator)
    
    coeff.reverse()
    
    return Polynomial(coeff)


def f(x,y):return sum(l(k,x)*y[k] for k in range(len(y)))


x=[101,0,-84,1]
y=[-42,12,3,12]
print(f"{l(0,x)=}\n")
print(f"{l(1,x)=}\n")
print(f"{l(2,x)=}\n")
print(f"{l(3,x)=}\n")
print("y[0]*l(0,x)+y[1]*l(1,x)+y[2]*l(2,x)+y[3]*l(3,x)== f(x):")
print(f(x,y))
```