# Generating generating expressions for sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer, polynomials

*(yes, "generating generating" in the title is correct :) )*

## Context

In middle (?) school we are taught about sequences and, in particular, we are taught about linear sequences where the `n`th term is generated with an expression of the form `an + b`, where `a` and `b` are some coefficients. In this challenge, we will deal with sequences generated by polynomials of arbitrary degree.

## Task

Given the first `m` terms of a sequence, find the coefficients of the polynomial of ***lowest*** degree that could have generated such a sequence.

A polynomial, and thus the generating expression you are looking for, is to be seen as a function \$p(n)\$ that takes `n` as an argument and returns

$$a_0 + a_1 n + a_2 n^2 + a_3 n^3 + \cdots + a_k n^k$$

where \$k \geq 0\$ and \$a_i, 0 \leq i \leq k\$ have to be found by you.

You will assume that the `m` terms you were given correspond to taking `n = 0`, `n = 1`, ..., `n = m-1` in the generating polynomial above.

### Examples

If I am given the sequence `[2, 2, 2]` then I realize this is a constant sequence and can be generated by a polynomial of degree `0`: `p(n) = 2`.

If I am given the sequence `[1, 2, 3]` then I realize this cannot come from a constant polynomial but it could come from a linear polynomial `p(n) = n + 1`, so that is what my output should be. Notice how

```
p(0) = 1
p(1) = 2
p(2) = 3    # and NOT p(1) = 1, p(2) = 2, p(3) = 3
```

## Input

Your input will be the first terms of a sequence, which you can take in any reasonable format/data type. A standard list is the most obvious choice.

You may assume the input sequence is composed of integers (positive, 0 and negative).

## Output

The coefficients of the polynomial of ***lowest*** degree that could have generated the input sequence. The output format can be in any sensible way, as long as the coefficients can be retrieved unambiguously from the output. For this, both the value of each coefficient and the degree of each coefficient are important. (e.g. if using a list, `[1, 0, 2]` is different from `[0, 1, 2]`).

You can assume the polynomial you are looking for has integer coefficients.

## Test cases

For these test cases, the input is a list with the first terms; the output is a list of coefficients where (0-based) indices represent the coefficients, so `[1, 2, 3]` represents `1 + 2x + 3x^2`.

```
[-2] -> [-2]
[0, 0] -> [0]
[2, 2, 2] -> [2]
[4, 4] -> [4]
[-3, 0] -> [-3, 3]
[0, 2, 4, 6] -> [0, 2]
[2, 6] -> [2, 4]
[3, 7] -> [3, 4]
[4, 8, 12, 16] -> [4, 4]
[-3, -1, 5, 15, 29] -> [-3, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 4, 9] -> [0, 0, 1]
[3, 2, 3, 6, 11] -> [3, -2, 1]
[3, 4, 13, 30, 55] -> [3, -3, 4]
[4, 12, 28, 52, 84] -> [4, 4, 4]
[2, 4, 12, 32, 70] -> [2, 1, 0, 1]
[3, 6, 21, 54] -> [3, -1, 3, 1]
[4, 2, 12, 52, 140] -> [4, -2, -3, 3]
[10, 20, 90, 280] -> [10, 0, 0, 10]
[-2, 8, 82, 352, 1022, 2368, 4738] -> [-2, 4, -1, 4, 3]
[4, 5, 32, 133, 380] -> [4, -2, 0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 71, 646, 2877, 8996, 22675] -> [1, -1, 0, -3, 0, 3]
[4, 2, 60, 556, 2540, 8094, 20692] -> [4, -2, -1, 0, -2, 3]
[1, 2, -17, 100, 1517, 7966, 28027, 78128, 186265] -> [1, 3, -2, 4, -3, -2, 1]
[4, 5, 62, 733, 4160, 15869, 47290, 118997] -> [4, 3, -1, -3, 1, 0, 1]
```

Test cases generated with [this code](https://tio.run/##XVLRboMwDHzPV1h9StYwQanUbVL3IyhCqJgOqQ0sSTtNVb@d2QHK1AdIcr6zz0763/DV2XwYGtedwVW2pqU9950L4BFrHbHWBsEnucuVEDU2cESLrgooDx02Xn0IgBqPDhH2cEI7wZBARhGP3wQXhrZN56CF1nLaI8pJs56ryEznKmYDuJImjTsWEVMDZ2Ux2sv5ufwoWe8j6aXvfmSrWaVijCy8Vn2PtpZXRhyGi7MMDwF9KA@VR88mKSZTDQV9qeHVKD1jycaM/xHajLRMw1bDu5lEBEzxnJCMz8TI3jTkOzMhE49yCyMEt2eXmWzS2I/D6lSSfzI1D4c0OzYfm2azcyChUlv1PNw5gzI04GKZ8FaZx6U83SPhyzjmgT0SadKMl@AVvYN/TE/vRaqxlVLDwmM3C4/76h27aFY3It0h@YRbJN5XavgD)

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it! If you dislike this challenge, please give me your feedback. Happy golfing!

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1729/75323)

Comment: May we take `m` as part of the input?

Comment: @RobinRyder only if it is standard in your language to take the length of a vector as an argument alongside the vector (like it is in C, for example)

Comment: @RobinRyder Just as note, there was a [relevant meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13210/31625) about this some time ago. The conclusions were more or less what was decided here, too.

Comment: Can we output in polynomial form (`1 + 2x + 3x^2`)?

Comment: @Uriel _"The output format can be in any sensible way, as long as the coefficients can be retrieved unambiguously"_ so yeah, you can!

Comment: Some answers round the resulting coefficients to integers, although I don’t read this as a hard requirement. Could you please  explicitly (not) require this?

Comment: Since the outputs can be assumed to be integers, is it OK to return near-zero (like 10⁻¹⁰ or smaller) numbers instead of proper zeros due to floating point errors?

Comment: @agtoever doing so, how do I draw the line between what is an acceptable error and what is not?

Comment: @Adám not sure; let me settle this with agtoever and your answer will probably come out of that.

Comment: Based on answers, I guess it's OK for the coefficient lists to include trailing zeroes? I wouldn't have thought that this would be allowed due to "Output: The coefficients of the polynomial of lowest degree..." But I think it indeed might make for a cleaner challenge not to require the extra step of removing trailing zeroes, which is how I expect most answers without built-ins would handle it.

Comment: @xnor when I saw the first answer with leading/trailing (depending on the order of the output) zeroes I also felt reluctant to accept them... But a 0 coefficient doesn't make the degree of the polynomial go up, as you know, and the zeroes don't mess with the unambiguous interpretation of the answers, so I allowed those.

Comment: @RGS That's fair. I was misunderstanding the "lowest degree" rule to refer to how the polynomials are shown in the output (without extraneous higher-power zero terms) rather than as a mathematical property of the polynomials themselves, which is of course not affected by how they are shown.

Comment: Arguably, the test case `[0, 0] -> [0]` would be more naturally, `[0, 0] -> []`, since the empty polynomial is already zero everywhere. But with the flexibility on trailing zeroes, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @xnor I don't think I ever heard of an "empty polynomial" , mathematically speaking. Is it a common thing? To me, an "empty function" sounds like something that would not be defined for any input, no? For the sake of argument, I would say the test case `0, 0 -> 0` does make sense :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106091/discussion-between-xnor-and-rgs).

Comment: Nothing related to the challenge, but "middle school" would actually be _high school_ in English. :) For me in The Netherlands we have "basisschool" (roughly ages 5-11), "middelbare school" (roughly ages 12-17), and "hoge school / universiteit" (roughly ages 18-24) (which literally translates to "basic school", "middle school", "high school / university"; but which would actually translate to "elementary school", "high school" and "college / university" respectively in English).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen  I mean [this middle school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_school#Portugal) from ages ~10 to ~15, which precedes "high school" but comes after "elementary school" here in Pt. It really is weird if in English there is nothing between elementary school and high school... Maybe [this standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_school#Levels_of_education) is more explicit? I meant level 2 of the ISCED 2011 levels :)

Comment: "You can assume the polynomial you are looking for has integer coefficients." - so does this mean we can output some coefficients with floating-point rounding errors? ...and does that include any higher-order zeros?

Comment: @JonathanAllan definitely not for higher order zero coefficients. As for the terms of lower degree, how can I enforce "reasonable" errors?

Comment: If they are errors due to floating-point inaccuracies you don't need to, it just comes under real-world machine inaccuracies. At present, for example, my Jelly answer rounds to 0 decimal places but accepts a list of integers each of which is unbounded, hence there exist inputs for which it will give incorrect answers as it is, so the three bytes of rounding I included actually adds no value as far as I can tell, but without them [some of the test cases yield sligtly inaccurate results](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/rUcNMrcP7Eg4v09J91Ljj8LLD0////x9tqKNgoKNgDqTMTMx0FIwszM11FCwsLUFsIzNz01gA).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I understand that floating-point inaccuracies arise naturally; what I mean is from the little experience I've had with this community, stating that "X is allowed as long as it occurs naturally" doesn't look very acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>193 ... 154</s>  145 bytes

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @Bubbler*

Returns \$(a_0,a_1,...,a_k)\$ with some possible trailing zeros.

```javascript
v=>v.map((_,i)=>(g=(i,m=v.map((n,y)=>v.map((_,x)=>x==i?n:y**x)))=>+m||m.reduce((s,[v],i)=>v*g(0,m.map(([,...r])=>r).filter(_=>i--))-s,0))(i)/g())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZXfbpswFMbv@xS@tFND/A8Dm8iu@hQRqlBKMqYQKtKhVOq7Z@fYuKXTqkGiEMDi@/yd3zHOr2qozru@eX6JTt1Tfd0X16HYDHFbPVP6yBtWbOihoA1vi3HwxF/Z5IkL3FyKovlx@va6Wl0Yg/v79u2tjfv66feupvTMt0PpnIbVgQreeumWx3HclzDcs3jfHF/qnj4WmyaKGIvOXDBGG7Y@UMau37d3hGwjVXKy7LNeOxmqBSdioR7VwokVJ/hdokexn9lwYm6Y2ThxpBfndkWDTIe6ITpksLNdXN1Y7li6vSE9zun0ECS9Qa@DHpJnnEjwk3NzOHpBjyQiyUkCBnCo/P8mAeA7A7iQjmG@lCEqAwYoAX4tjMhZNiOGSE08IIPE1oJvksxwCR5TnMhSAdMEzpmZh8O4qU1YEaOLhiMVM2MoB3EKBFAo7IxZ0NexmzrYGMcVw2A50ojZ9SDXj9dEYrPhyPGczXrj0Ef6HmNVfqdAV2CbIR2XSCjErS0MmlRn/zD2m5SDGvllpkNpiWcsNeackWpSmn/vPSTPPYWTNQg9S1OImOd4rWyafBFK@kDCcxKTXLgpuCWIDomBy0zkOC5srr5wC8hHR/W5TItLCcs0Ep1lktkciSlsiJQQNi3/thvXAoZ7X1nlXbzv@odq95NWpNiQXXc6d8c6PnYHuqcV/D1d/wA)

(removed the penultimate test case, which requires more precision than IEEE-754 provides)

#### How?

We use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) to solve a system of linear equations based on a square [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix):

1. Given an input vector of length \$n\$, we build a Vandermonde matrix \$V_n\$ of size \$n\times n\$ with coefficients \$\alpha_i=i,0\le i <n\$:

   $$Vn=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&0&0&...&0\\
   1&1&1&...&1\\
   1&2&4&...&2^{n-1}\\
   \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
   1&n-1&(n-1)^2&...&(n-1)^{n-1}
   \end{pmatrix}$$
2. Using Cramer's rule, the coefficient \$a_i\$ of the polynomial is computed by taking the determinant of the matrix obtained by replacing the \$i\$-th column of \$V_n\$ with the input vector, and dividing by the determinant of \$V_n\$.

#### Example for \$(4,2,12,52,140)\$

The constant coefficient \$a_0\$ is given by:

$$a_0=\begin{vmatrix}
\color{blue}4&0&0&0&0\\
\color{blue}2&1&1&1&1\\
\color{blue}{12}&2&4&8&16\\
\color{blue}{52}&3&9&27&81\\
\color{blue}{140}&4&16&64&256
\end{vmatrix}/|V_5|=\frac{1152}{288}=4$$

The coefficient \$a_1\$ is given by:

$$a_1=\begin{vmatrix}
1&\color{blue}4&0&0&0\\
1&\color{blue}2&1&1&1\\
1&\color{blue}{12}&4&8&16\\
1&\color{blue}{52}&9&27&81\\
1&\color{blue}{140}&16&64&256
\end{vmatrix}/|V_5|=\frac{-576}{288}=-2$$

And so on.

Comment: -4 bytes by replacing `m.reduce(...)` with `m.reduceRight((s,[v],i)=>v*g(0,m.map(([,...r])=>r).filter(_=>i--))-s,0)`.

Comment: @Bubbler Very nice!

Comment: Looks like `reduce` instead of `reduceRight` also works -- it would invert the sign of even-sized(?) matrices' determinants, but the same inversion happens on both numerator and denominator, cancelling each other. (It gives spurious `-0`s, but `-0==0` anyway.)

Comment: @Bubbler Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
round(solve(outer(n<-seq(a=u<-scan())-1,n,"^"))%*%u)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAryxCsBsKJioJ9ZVAylsoadv3zdswtfdaOF/Yyv0lLPyminlTLT0Ydx44Y0YitcgsxSGIpnli6hYMeA3OeTDOalh1GKV9MP0H)

Outputs \$(a_0, a_1,\ldots,)\$ with possible trailing zeros.

Let \$u\$ be the output sequence, and \$X\$ be the \$m\times m\$ matrix such that \$X_{i,j}=i^j\$ (0-indexed), i.e.

\$
X=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&\ldots&0\\
1&1&1&\ldots&1\\
1&2&4&\ldots&2^{m-1}\\
1&3&9&\ldots&3^{m-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&m-1&(m-1)^2&\ldots&(m-1)^{m-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
\$

Then in matrix notation, \$u=Xa\$, hence \$a=X^{-1}u\$.

The code implements this: `n` is the vector `(0, 1, ..., m-1)` where `m` is the length of `u`; this is used to construct `X = outer(n, n, "^")`. The function `solve` performs matrix inversion, and the `round` is there to avoid numerical errors.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAryxCsBsKJioJ9ZVAylsoadv3zdswtfdaOF/Yyv0lLPyminlTLT0Ydx44Y0YitcgsxSGIpnli6hYMeA3OeTDOalh1GKV9MP0H)

Comment: [alternative 55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9S2ODkxT0PTuii/NC9FIydXo7SuID@nUsPAKk8nz0Y3JzUvvSRDo1RT11CnKLHcNkRTUyU5X/O/iYKRgpmBgqmpmYKRqYmBgoWBJVDIwMzS6D8A)

Comment: Note you need the `a=` in the `seq` statement for the first test case `-2`.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! I really need to remember about `seq_along`; this isn't the first time you've improved one of my answers with that!

Comment: I have this niggling feeling that R has an inbuilt function to do this, but I cannot for the life of me think what it is (and it would probably be disqualified anyway)

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, 16 bytes

Index origin = 0

Prompts for input as a vector and outputs coefficients from a0 to an-1 where n is the length of the vector. The order of the polynomial can be obtained by summing the number of coefficients up to the last none zero coefficient:

```
0⍕n⌹m∘.*m←⍳⍴n←,⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##LU9LTgMxDN3PKbxGFNlO4iRHQAJxhqpoENK0IHXVC0AXFLGpxC26gA3bHiUXGV6saiTPi/0@9vJ1WjzultPL02I1Lbfb59XcPo/3d@3tKwxAtw9APLT9@zhzOxw37eNv3fbfN1drDNrhpx1@N0DX4M5gzeNwPukwDkyMqoQP/0hx6JPgXUY3kvm810DZOYVESezCPJ@EEkkira4RaKqzlQIZifgjkgQKTCm5Bxy0UFIq0f29E5QyO9tI4Rqdqn0EpsQ@E2zFVFEL@wawoAJtZ7DCNlihmENxceqmEhDtdCGmLGQRASVnKrUCqeV0ibK@IVopMhWuaLFVdaX2UzNCcGMCyNW6CytgEVwjxdTSJdZwC2KjWKcXq9hJsbYIMvM/)

Comment: Nice solution; wouldn't have thought of it! Pretty sure you can golf it down even further to 13 bytes with either of `{⍵⌹m∘.*m←⍳⍴⍵}` or, closer to your style, `n⌹b∘.*b←⍳⍴n←⎕` :)

Comment: @AviF.S. Thanks for your suggestion but the first option is not available in APL+WIN and the second the comma before quad is to force a vector if a scalar is entered and the 0⍕ is required to filter out the extremely small errors that can occur and display as nonexistent coefficients

Comment: You're totally right about the `,` being necessary to vectorize! I looked at the other test cases, but didn't notice the domain error with the scalar; you're totally right! About the `0⍕`, I'm curious which test cases yielded errors. I haven't been able to reproduce any, but then again *TIO* is running Dyalog classic and not APL+WIN, could that be the difference?

Comment: @AviF.S. Take [10, 20, 90, 280] -> [10, 0, 0, 10] for example without 0⍕ the result would be 10 ¯9.371726267E¯15 1.308691287E¯14 10 as opposed to 10 0 0 10

Comment: @AviF.S. if you can golf my approach down using a modern rather than my ancient APL with your own entry by all means do so as I like to see APL being able to compete with golfing languages.

Comment: No way am I taking any credit for your clever answer! However, I do want to point out that in Dyalog `10 20 90 280` does indeed yield `10 0 0 10` with only `n⌹b∘.*b←⍳⍴n←,⎕` . I'm sure someone else will come along and let us know what the history there is :) For now, since your *TIO* link is to Dyalog anyway, seems like you can just change the language name to be Dyalog as well and shave off 2 bytes! [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tf96jnp25jzpm6GnlAgUf9W5@1LslD8jSAar7D1TxP43L0EDByEDBEkhaGAAA)

Comment: Why the `,` if you specify that input has to be a vector?

Comment: @Adám Force of  habit. I have written lots of code that requires vector input and had users input a scalar. Rightly or wrongly I always assume TIO will nor recognise vector input if a user simply enters one number as in the first example

Comment: OK, but for code golf purposes, you can definitely be strict towards the "user" and require a proper vector as input.

Comment: @AviF.S. `⊢⌹∘.*⍨∘⍳∘≢` is the shortest I can make it.

Comment: @Adám In the context of APL do all golfers know the difference when trying out our code on TIO

Comment: @Graham I'd say yes. If they are even slightly interested in APL/J/K (otherwise, why are they looking at the TIO?) they'll understand that. If you want it completely clear to *everyone*, you can use `⎕JSON'[1,2,3]'` and `⎕JSON '[42]'`.

Comment: And to think that some people claim that APL isn't legible...

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 37 bytes

Returns a polynomial.

Mathematica is so awesome `x+1` can be used as a variable in this context. `Apart` is a weird built-in that, quoting from the docs, seems to attempt to rewrite an expression as a sum of terms with minimal denominators, and also happens to expand polynomials (that are returned in a weird collapsed form by default) into something more sane.

```
Apart@InterpolatingPolynomial[#,x+1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxC8IwFIR3f0VAcPEJfWn7kgxCXQpu3WuHIEUDaVJCBkX622Pi4HLcd8fdouNzXnQ0d5368y1dVh1id3VxDqu3OXePwdu384vRdtzD64jTIQ3BuNj14weBcWAnFMCwqrK0xQpFlAtZ8QISucyNJE7tNu3@2wZYC4zyXtQ1sAbpdyBJZRBcFUKplNim9AU)

## [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer), 8 bytes

<sup>(it will try to deceive you into thinking it's actually 7.5, but it's actually not)</sup>

```
⣕⢤⣏⠛⡪⣊⠵⢼
```

Explanation: It's `Apart@InterpolatingPolynomial[Input[], x+1]`, but compressed via an awesome Mathematica compressor (it is so awesome that, as far as I understand, it translates Mathematica to an intermediate stack-based language).

Unfortunately, running this is fairly painful.

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYw9C8IwGIR3f0VAcPEV8qZtPgZBEAqCQ/faIZRUA20iNUNF2r8eUweX45477gYdHmbQwbY6lsdbvLhgxqfvU@Lule/fzg9W9/UWpj02y9mbrrOtNS5c7Sss0y5Wo3XhVNYfBMKAHFAAQUqTFKsVivNUSMpWkMhkaiRnvJibzX@bAymA8LQXWQYkR/47kFwlEEythFIpMTfxCw "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: According to the comments under the question you can also return the polynomial itself rather than its coefficients, which gets you to [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYyxCsIwFEV3vyIguPiEvrR9SQahiwW37jVD0KKBNiklQ0X67TFxcLncw@HeyYTXMJlg7ya251u8rLNxj@bqwrDMfkzCPTs/vp2frBn7PaxH1IfYLdaFpu0/CIwDO6EAhkWRos5VKKIkZMEzSOQyGUmc6k3v/tsKWA2M0l6UJbAK6XcgSSUQXGVCqZTYdPwC)

Comment: @LukasLang Nice. Reading the docs for `Expand`, I noticed `Apart` that achieves the same thing for one byte less in this case.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
%.^/~@i.@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/VfXi9OscMvUclP9r/k9TMKhQMKxQMKrgSlPQiQdTRhUQBGSaVCiYViiYAbnmxsYVCiaGZiDlphZmlkCOuZEliGdoYWlpXgEA)

Obligatory J answer on a matrix-related challenge. Takes input as a vector of extended integers (otherwise the answer may have small floating-point errors), and gives the polynomial's coefficients in lowest-first order, possibly with some extra zeroes at the end.

#### How it works

```
%.^/~@i.@#  NB. Input: a vector V of extended integers.
         #  NB. Length of V
      i.@   NB. Generate 0..(len(V)-1)
  ^/~@      NB. Self outer product by ^(exponentiation)
%.          NB. Matrix-divide V by the matrix above,
            NB.   i.e. solve a linear system of equations
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 38 bytes

```
a->Vecrev(polinterpolate([0..#a-1],a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDRasMwDPwV072kYBdLsWX7Yf2MvZQ8mJGOQllDKIN9fXZyPApxTj6dTpKXut7c17JdzbvZqjt/zJ/r/DMsj/vt@zmvwPqch4s/nd6qo8nW43Gry3L/HapxZ7OskCE86OVgrgPy1lwujieAt8YrsjX6aRisCYpu7DnfcqClKxsim7o8W0OgSf7LHFkTQeBw6RbULEovhRx/AU2dQZIAI6QxdmN1ZbhHYA69e@dHnOR7MYxYe4ZeyLtG6yg0EekWOEUxN8pxGz2rWVN61n6jgAxpzN0r7r1o1On2SrSCTQJI0NY5JfiUojFLiq8ppK2jfAwIsy/KeyncfVhfK2lzfaOoYSrSTD3rJZO@AGVhia@JRLfXiQJJK8xSdGrW/YgwS5qm4/YH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + Numpy, 69 bytes

```python
lambda x:polyfit(range(len(x)),x,len(x)-1).round()
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLRbqMwEHxuvsJvgRNEtjHGVOr9SNuH3MXpIRGDgFSJon57uuMlcJXirL2e3Znx0l@nf10o7seXt3u7P/057MXlue/a67GZkmEfPnzS@pBc0jS7ZLzLVbobunM4JOnmOHQnEc6n/iqaU98N0687RzFex83kx2kUL9jvxunQhN3g97GsG0TbBC@aICJoN/YtEW7fwjZ93jw1oT9PmejOE0VqAOwDIvLfYptunvqhCVNy3N4i@Avp2zHxn/s2iZk0/cqEv/T@7@QP4tY2Ixnyn34Y/YFh3D4l4Da9v@b6HT0QN68yE5KPkk46E/hxAtcmE4ZPhk55saCxLbieKghm5y4oj43mBG4pQfCKEwUnqMRlQtG1mpGGL9A5V5ko6YaWrlfCuTkFFTnrhRMpZqGG9G/prBa@XC/XVKUgnQrKcgWsoqBIk7KSojOrMgawV2AKWpVcPKr/NRC7hgOzEqgoSzGH5hagUEYuHJD5eFcFr7RqRDdjFDsFEaYFPCl1UBN7SQ3xhaWkqQr3GHPUnPOTFaygZAOqAJ37KYFHCqlsqqJgDTy5qiK6usZe22p@P8XNJYuXCwe@gfjMgJeGtk7WyEtb65@m53I9e4@1uapgCWZLbKvaRg1S4@AUhqSc1XaVMY/asJLH1Nmuxbxg1ygbezpb45k0XlgpclUtmuaBocljrt8)

May have leading zeros.

Comment: The output doesn't have to be reversed, you can give the coefficient list from highest degree to lowest, so 69 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer

Comment: I think you can skip the `-1`: this gives an extra leading 0, but this is allowed. Saves you 2 bytes.

Comment: If you use Python 3.8 with PEP572 (assignment expressions), you can save another 2 bytes with `l:=len(x)` for the first `len` and replace the second `len(x)` with just `l`.

Comment: I can't find numpy for pyhon 3.8

Comment: @agtoever it doesn't work, it errors

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>68</s> 62 bytes

```
≔⟦¹⟧ηＦＬθ«⊞υ⁰≔÷⁻§θιΣＥυ×κＸιλ∨ΠＥι⊕κ¹ζＵＭυ⁺κ×ζ§ηλ⊞η⁰≔Ｅη⁻§η⊖λ×κιη»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBbS8MwGH1ef0Uev0CETQUf@lQ2hILFwnwrfahtXD6ai8tljom/vSa1Kgskge@cnEt60dnedHKaCufwoKHZtIwImmdvxhJ44vrgBRwpJZ/Zqg5OQGBkHeHVwi@13@EJBw4V6uCg8KUe@BmOjCBlZB8UVN17evWCijsYGanNB7eAjEiaFiPPFmprhtD7mRuRUveWK649H2CcOZt0XJJxpGyNUp0ekmotwyz6o35h5DeAWPTzJbe4zp2M4ug6dBzs@L@zTJ5/sXHOkb7mK6stag/bznl4ROljnRil6s6oYt/i1RkZPIe9xJ4nZJyL0nyamuaWkftYJ153cT@s23a6Oclv) Link is to verbose version of previous version of code that excludes trailing zeros, but apparently it isn't necessary to do that, thus saving 6 bytes. Outputs the terms in power order i.e. the constant term is printed first. Explanation:

```
≔⟦¹⟧η
```

Start by creating a helper polynomial \$ h(x) = 1 \$.

```
ＦＬθ«
```

Loop over the \$ m \$ terms.

```
⊞υ⁰
```

Add a \$ 0x^i \$ term to the result polynomial \$ u(x) \$.

```
≔÷⁻§θιΣＥυ×κＸιλ∨ΠＥι⊕κ¹ζ
```

Subtract the value of \$ u(i) \$ from the input term and divide that by \$ i! \$.

```
ＵＭυ⁺κ×ζ§ηλ
```

Multiply \$ h \$ by that value and add the result to \$ u \$. This doesn't change the values of \$ u(0) ... u(i-1) \$ but the value of \$ u(i) \$ is now the input term.

```
⊞η⁰≔Ｅη⁻§η⊖λ×κιη
```

Multiply \$ h \$ by \$ x - i \$.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Print the coefficients of \$ u \$, which may include trailing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
h%(a:t)=h-a:a%t
h%_=[h]
f(h:t)=h:foldr(%)[](f$zipWith((/).(-h+))t[1..])
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJNb5wwEL3zK@aQlaDBFBt/sQq595BzDxStnC0sq7AELVYVRf3toTNeR6mEmeHNe2/GNqNbX/pp2rZxl7q9z5qRub3b@WTcHZp27JIhHQO8H16n39d0l7VdOty9n5efZz@m6fesSNl4n2W@5UXRZckAfdNv/R83HZyHt@Ym@@XgmT26@@dvb1mZYHGFBRpoP3npcH29/Jh9f7q6CeYMlr8zPDBoy6KY@vnkR1i6Lkl8v/rD0a39SuqWiS5HTg4lRZEDPZTKHCRFVsVaGWoI68gMEasm0m0OHGGuP2WM56AQwCXqaMGDRR2lSMe3RphHBIscQ4VUpaIxuQp0VxitjN0jXuEyZRSjkaCeMgrFjUM6LgOJ0y5w1RRtgJgIo1syC8xSUL9KIyhNZaOXuvXiFU13U2IrtDEYtKTW1hj0qWvKhTbqawodtkO4kpjasia81LWIPoJOy1BzOiNFqal1MC0FfVhOJ8CtFlp9TaRp9zSR5DoIra5pakH74xxnMXTnF3ee8bYvbnmC5XqePdzRBwzw39@wfRyHyZ3WjR2X5R8)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
⊢⌹∘.*⍨∘⍳∘≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CsJQDEZ3nyKzqNzktvdndrGTYH2BgtSloKuzULTYooPg3Mmtg5NrHyUvck3t8n0n4STZsZjvTllx2Adunsmay7sKXLV8@/LltZhy/Zbm@jPktQ25CFw3o1ud@05z@ZAp3Swlt6skDTlEEIMhsFpDhEYBxs54iCx5YXTe28koaQIUSTv1XzhAWRjhGUkQDInSfYcWUA2fBKw3BsgpEnRIcuUMmfgH)

A port of [Graham's APL+WIN solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202828/78410) into a modern APL, which happens to work exactly the same (and have the same byte count) as [my own J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202838/78410).

#### How it works

```apl
⊢⌹∘.*⍨∘⍳∘≢  ⍝ Input: V, result of a polynomial evaluated at 0..m-1
       ⍳∘≢  ⍝ Generate 0..m-1
  ∘.*⍨∘     ⍝ Self outer product by * (exponentiation)
⊢⌹          ⍝ Matrix divide V by above (solve linear system of equations)
```

Comment: APL smashes the competition. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>48</s> 47 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
g≠iā<DδmUεXøINǝ}Xšεā<sUœε©2.ÆíÆ.±Xε®Nèè}«P}O}ć÷
```

Sometimes 05AB1E's lack of almost all matrix builtins is pretty annoying.. ;)
Inspired by [@Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202829/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//VHngswjjTYu57bkhp7bGnF4h6ff8bm1EUcXntsKFC4OPTr53NZDK430DrcdXnu4Te/Qxgggf53f4RWHV9QeWh1Q6197pP3w9v//o010jHQMjXRMgaSJQex/Xd28fN2cxKpKAA) or [verify almost all test cases](https://tio.run/##NY69SkNBEIVfJaQ@G3Zn/0FIYx1tIpGQQkEkoKYICBFuYROxE60F7SKiIBi0zibY3YfIi1zn3lUWdnbOfufMTKZHx@OT6nLWbbe28/tWuztLdwfV6fb2aby@3tktP8/75XKQvg97P4/FYPNcLlme9jcP5XL1Qp00T29p3ll9DLh/76VFWhSr1/1ir1jfpK@qQDUcChqhNZSQdSHwqR8Gpi5CZ12ybuAy0hQNn7kARVDujxYKFsqCYrYptsXMEzQclMqdgdLQEtbmGA6hAEsIJk9pJE3wMhsciLNNpqn@ZFiZ5lfxfhKR79D0gmMQ2F4jkjhauwDjdch2WwcrzQtkXkHCKzjDQ4L3CDHyi5y3/@NcvSlr1kgEGVmSLtJoVAlxMRFnR1ezXw) (removed the last two largest ones, since they time out on TIO).

**Explanation:**

First handle the edge case of a single-element input-list (would cause issues with the `«` later on in the code):

```python
g                # Get the length of the (implicit) input-list
 ≠i              # And if it is NOT 1, continue with:
                 #  ... (see below)
                 # (implicit else:)
                 #  (output the implicit input-list as implicit output)
```

Next we'll get the exponentiation matrix of the list `[0, input-length)`:

```python
ā                #  Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length] (without popping)
 <               #  Decrease each value by 1 to make the range [0, input-length)
  Dδ             #  Apply double-vectorized on itself by first duplicating:
    m            #   Take the power of the two values
     U           #  Pop and store this exponentiation matrix in variable `X`
```

Next we'll create a list of this matrix, with every column one by one replaced with the input-list:

```python
ε     }          #  Map over the input-list that was still on the stack
 X               #   Push the exponentiation matrix from variable `X`
  ø              #   Zip/transpose it; swapping rows/columns
     ǝ           #   Replace the transposed row of the exponentiation matrix
    N            #   at the current map-index
   I             #   with the input-list
```

We'll prepend the original exponentiation matrix to this list:

```python
Xš               #  Prepend the matrix `X` in front of this list
```

And we'll [calculate the determinant of each inner matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202866/52210) in this list:

```python
ε              } #  Map over the list of matrices:
 ā               #   Push a list in the range [1, matrix-length] (without popping)
  <              #   Decrease it by 1 to make the range [0, matrix-length)
   sU            #   Swap to get the matrix again, and pop and store it in variable `X`
     œ           #   Get all permutations of the [0, matrix-length) list
      ε          #   Inner map over each permutation:
       ©         #    Store the current permutation in variable `®` (without popping)
        2.Æ      #    Get all 2-element combinations of this permutation
           í     #    Reverse each inner pair
            Æ    #    Reduce it by subtracting
             .±  #    And get it's signum (-1 if a<0; 0 if a==0; 1 if a>0)
       X         #    Push the matrix from variable `X`
        ε        #    Map over each of its rows:
         ®       #     Push the current permutation of variable `®`
          Nè     #     Get the value in the permutation at the current map-index
            è    #     And use that to index into the current matrix-row
        }«       #    After the map of rows: merge it together with the signum list
          P      #    And take the product of this entire list
      }O         #   After the map of permutations: sum all values
```

Now that we have all determinants of the matrices, we get the default one again to divide all others by it:

```python
ć                #  Extract head: pop and push remainder-list and first item separated
 ÷               #  Integer-divide each value in the remainder-list by this head
                 #  (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [24](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BSXaL9Ql8PdyoeW1l7YG6F4eLttxJEGrUcd82wicrV0//@P1jXSUbAAIiBlbAokDA2MgKSRsRlQ0MTc2CIWAA) without using matrices. Feels like just brute-forcing polynomials could be even shorter.

Comment: [23](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Otov1OVwt/KhpbUX9kYoHt5u@6hjnk1E7qE1ylq6LkB5XSMdBQsgAlLGpkDC0MAISBoZmwEFTcyNLWIB)

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, it's in reverse order of course. Still, the `[4,5,62,733,4160,15869,47290,118997]` test case lacks its `0` between the `1`s. Same applies to some of the other test cases, like `[-3,-1,5,15,29]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), <s>63</s> 48 bytes

```py
lambda v:QQ[x].lagrange_polynomial(enumerate(v))
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdUNtqwzAMfe9XGPaSQDMsX2R7sI_ocwnDY2kpJGkJXdn-fkd2Ry9gLOlIOjrSTr2rMU-fX1ld3jab7U__Oub9kuf98HE6jr_zcTrksRnm72lY8nloLm27Wp2Ww3xuds22M2sV8WCsx0fa4DeWAbpgY9-26kWVMrdWHRVj-xsBQg9EWq2FE_W1RcqBarAhd9dBBQww7BjZGAIEpCS-4eCv_VTHobSzxTxNBSsD9V76vIMbdRJcczKPGv55zCMJFZKOgqyNPHlxQ-KiShsJIhlcgiIbvhNmK5mr2rqnBetJGGiQkzjiQh45yU1NkoiwcLiptFWksFWt1P8BFfhozA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Outputs the polynomial as

$$a_k n^k + \cdots + a_3 n^3 + a_2 n^2 + a_1 n + a_0 $$

Comment: I don't understand how to use the "try it online" link you provide

Comment: Shalom Uriel. Baruch mechayei hameitim!

Comment: @RGS wrong link, fixed :)

Comment: @Adám Thanks! Long time away

Comment: Aren't there any test cases for which those floats come with errors? Because we are only dealing with integers so you are expected to return the exact coefficients.

Comment: @RGS forget what I said - updated to use the Rationals ring that gives integer answers

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
n:qGyz3$ZQYo
```

The result is given with higher-order coefficients first, and may contain leading zeros.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8@q0L2yylglKjAy////aF1jHQVdQx0FUx0FQyA2sowFAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PVC7TgQxDOz5ihSUWSl2EsehPokaiYY7nQQ9DyFRwP38MhOfTtqsnbFnPM7H28/7/rp/Pnw//l3q/fHp5Ws/HH@f99Om57tTyakgaE78kLWcGsJWo1BWAaBFFwNKIzo9JwEodmVsklPHHUdnsGWxZ9DQi78BlQBQEoSKxt5Dk4IK4Y7oLaZe4YozSjAhopzWgqXRQZI0tgid40xGJ7LpMuwUWn1FOaoawDaqh1CPMVJpa/EwBRoDwRqn@hhQmZO52ug3A7a2INwbUi@TeLGpoaJ8oMHBfJfOdExbkkV5ceHi4qbWb26MS9NNE1s8t0nDys1EYGSc/wE)

#### Explanation

Consider input `[-3, -1, 5, 15, 29]` as an example.

```
n:q    % Implicit input. Number of elements. Range. Subtract 1, element-wise
       % STACK: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
G      % Push input again
       % STACK: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [-3, -1, 5, 15, 29]
yz     % Duplicate from below. Number of non-zero elements
       % STACK: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [-3, -1, 5, 15, 29], 4
3$ZQ   % Fit polynomial with inputs x, y, degree
       % STACK: [3.7536e-16, -3.1637e-15, 2.0000, -8.8363e-15, -3]
Yo     % Round, element-wise. Implicit display
       % STACK: [0, 0, 2, 0, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
J’*þ`æ*-⁸æ×ær0
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of integers which yields a list of the exponents (floats and/or integers) with the lowest degree on the left of the same length as the input (with trailing zeros if need be).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/rUcNMrcP7Eg4v09J91Ljj8LLD0w8vKzL4//9/tKGOgoGOgjmQMjMx01EwsjA311GwsLQEsY3MzE1jAQ)**

#### How?

```
J’*þ`æ*-⁸æ×ær0 - Link: list of integers, V
J              - range of length (V)
 ’             - decrement (vectorises)
    `          - use as both arguments of:
   þ           -   outer-product using:
  *            -     exponentiation
       -       - minus one
     æ*        - matrix-exponentiation (i.e. inverse)
        ⁸      - chain's left argument, V
         æ×    - matrix-multiplication
           ær0 - round to zero decimal places (vectorises)
```